# How to load a self Signed website on React native Webview

Tags: react-native, android-webview

I want to load a https url using a WebView on React Native. 
However, it doesn't load. 
I don't want to manually add the CA on Trust Source of the device.

Anyone knows a solution for it? 
I'm Ok, even if it requires some native implementation.

Comment: I only find a way of overcome it. I override react native WebViewPackager. Then, onReceivedSslError I ignore the ssl error and did handler.proceed();

Comment: Where is located the file where you made those changes? I'm having the same issue and I need to solve it, even if it's needed to edit those files. Thank you!

Comment: I'd like to know which Android files did you edit so I am able to edit them too, if necessary, yes! For example, now I need to override a function on the native WebView called `onPermissionRequest()`, just as your `onReceivedSslError()`, but I am not able to know where I have to override it, so your indications could help me a lot! Thank you!

Comment: @Oximer can you show here how did you override the WebViewPackager?

Answer (score 3):

I have a workaround for this (it's terrible and it's hacky but it works)

Go to node_modules/react-native-webview/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/webview/RNCWebViewManager.java

Add these to the imports at the top:

```
import android.net.http.SslError;
import android.webkit.SslErrorHandler;
```

Then add this around line 807 (below onRecievedHttpError):

```
    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView webView, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
      handler.proceed();
    }
```

Bam! Now you will no longer check for ssl errors. Watch out though, it's dangerous

Comment: This was the only thing that woked for dev testing.

Comment: This worked for me too, thanks. I just wrapped it in `if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)` so it would be in debug only.

Comment: But this will be overridden once you reinstall node modules

Answer (score 0):

Actually it does. The problem might be, you need to define height from styles. you just need to call the url and you don't need to deploy any CA things. WebView doesn't change height automatically.

```
<WebView
    source={{ uri: https//www.sample.com }}
    style={{ width: 300, height: 300 }}
/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately no. I able to make it open more website like www.google.com. So, I sure that it's not layout issues.